# How do I check if a particular app is installed on the user's device on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, instagram

Is there a function which I can use to check if the user has a particular app installed on their device. Ie, instagram

Answer (score 5):

```
class func isAppInstalled(_ appName:String) -> Bool{

    let appScheme = "\(appName)://app"
    let appUrl = URL(string: appScheme)

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appUrl! as URL){
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }

}
```

Add the name of the app you are checking to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in your info.plist file

[image]

Comment: it stopped working!